Unable to download dependency for android
Could not find io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.1.
Unable to get the realm dependency for legacy project the project in ran in Android studio version 4.0 and gradle wrapper properties is 4:10
I have tried different realm version till the latest one. All version returns same issue

buildscript {
repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
google()
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.1"
classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
maven{url "https://maven.google.com"}
maven{url 'https://jitpack.io'}
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
google()
}
}

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
